# How to Access enum from header file into main program in C?

Tags: c, enums, header

I have created a .h file in C that contains a enum 'app'. This enum value need to be accessed in the main.c program. My code looks something like this:

```
 state.h file

#ifndef State_H_
#define State_H_

#define enum app {A,D,H};

#endif
```

My main program is :

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "State.h"

char letters[] ={'AAAA'};
if( letters[0] ==State.app[0])
{
   printf("the first letter is matching");
}
```

But here in the if statement the State.app[0] gives an error

Error: State could not be resolved,
          app could not be resolved.

Could somebody please suggest a way in which I could access the enum values from the header file. Please note that the int main and return are part of the program. I have just not included them here.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: do (don't) you get any warnings?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Nope. I just get this error. No warnings.

Comment: Do not use single character names for global objects!

Comment: look closely `'AAAA'`....

Comment: And.. `#define enum ....` is a really weird construct. Well, what @Olaf said.

Comment: @Olaf: I am just a beginner in C. So i guess there might be mistakes here and there. I was trying out header files(and accessing data from them) and this was something I did as an example exercise

Comment: @Goldengirl Unfortunately there are mistakes in nearly every line, and in the general approach as well. You can't compare characters with `enum` values.

Comment: It's not "mistakes here and there", but you do confuse basic concepts (character literas vs. enums for instance. These are described in a good C book very closely. Their understanding is **vital** for any further programming success. So either ask a friend to explain all this, or read a book or find a tutorial (there are many online for free).

Comment: @Olaf :Thank you. Will try and do that before moving on :)

Answer (score 2):

State doesn't define a 'namespace' (like in C#), so you can't access the **type** (with enum you're defining a **type**) by using as prefix the name of the header.

you should define enum like this:

```
enum app = { AA, BB, CC };
```

You can define 'State' as a local variable if you want.

```
enum app State;
```

Then assign a value:

```
State = AA;
```

What you're trying to do it's still unclear to me, though.

Answer (score 1):

Many, many issues.

First of all,

```
#define enum app {A,D,H};
```

doesn't create an enumerated type; instead, it creates a *macro* named `enum` that will be replaced with the text `app {A,D,H};` whenever it appears in your code.  If you want to create an enumerated type, just write

```
enum app {A, D, H};
```

Second of all, an enumerated type does not act like an array; you don't access enumeration values using array subscript syntax such as `app[0]`.  You use the *enumeration constant* `A`, `D`, or `H`.  Also, the header file does not create a namespace; you don't use `State` as a prefix for anything.

Finally, the enumeration constant `A` is not the same thing as the character constant `'A'`, and it won't automatically have the same value.  You will have to explicitly initialize the enumeration constant with the value you want, like so:

```
enum app { A = 'A', D = 'D', H = 'H' };
```

So, putting everything together, your code will look something like this:

```
/**
 * State.h
 */
#ifndef State_H_
#define State_H_

enum app { A = 'A', D = 'D', H = 'H' };

#endif

/**
 * main.c
 */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "State.h"

int main( void )
{
  char letters[] ={'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'}; // thanks NiBZ.
  if( letters[0] == A)      // no qualifier, just the bare enum constant
  {
     printf("the first letter is matching");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

As NiBZ points out, there's a problem with the declaration

```
char letters[] ={'AAAA'};
```

If you want a simple array of characters, then the initializer needs to look like

```
char letters[] = {'A', 'A', 'A', 'A' };
```

If you want `letters` to be a *string* (sequence of characters terminated by a 0-valued byte), then the initializer needs to look like either

```
char letters[] = {'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 0 };
```

or

```
char letters[] = "AAAA";
```

**END EDIT**

Having said all that, this code feels very confused.  If the enumeration constant `A` has special meaning beyond simply being the value of the character constant `'A'`, you should use a more meaningful name for your enumeration constant.  For example, if `'A'` indicates the beginning of a record or something use a name like `RECORD_BEGIN` instead of `A`:

```
if ( letters[0] == RECORD_BEGIN )
```

Otherwise, just use the bare character constant:

```
if ( letters[0] == 'A' )
```

Comment: You kept the `char letters[] = {'AAAA'};`. Using something like `char letters[] = "AAAA";` would be ... better ;)

Comment: @NiBZ: derp.  I'll fix that.